# Can't open "source.extension.vsixmanifest" file in Designer Mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsix, vspackage, visual-studio-package

I have Visual Studio 2012 Package Project (from VS2012 SDK). I can't remember what I have done before, but at this moment I get a following error when I try to open `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file in designer mode: "**An item with the same key has already been added**". I am able to open this file only in "View Code" mode.

Moreover, what is weird, If I create another VS2012 Package Project in this Solution, the same error appears for the corresponding `source.extension.vsixmanifest` in the new project.

It looks like a dictionary or resources duplicated key problem. But I haven't modified any resources or dictionaries.

What is the reason of this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you publish your _source.extension.vsixmanifest_ content? Did you search for duplicated keys in it? Or just search for keys used in it to ensure they are not duplicated in other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem.
On my System, the cause were projects with duplicate names that I created to have separate but similiar project templates for different Visual Studio versions. Renaming the projects solved it for me.